# (typed) list of argument from a program using optparse-appplicative

Tags: haskell, optparse-applicative

Is there a way to extract a list of names and types from a command line program, made using `optparse-applicative` ?

I am +/- looking for some function of type `ParserInfo a -> [(String,TypeRep)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no way. The relevant bits are:

```
data ParserInfo a = ParserInfo   
    { infoParser :: Parser a
    , -- ...
    }

data Parser a
  = forall x . MultP (Parser (x -> a)) (Parser x)
  | forall x . BindP (Parser x) (x -> Parser a)
  | -- ...
```

Since the `x`s of `MultP` and `BindP` are existentially quantified and do not carry a `Typeable` constraint, the information about the types used at the leaves of a `Parser a` tree is lost at runtime.

Comment: great point. one can get "names only" with `work2 :: Parser a -> IO ()
work2 p = (mapParser (\_ -> optionNames . optMain) p ) & print`