# Generate command line strings using optparse-applicative

Tags: haskell, optparse-applicative

Given a [`Parser a`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/optparse-applicative-0.14.3.0/docs/Options-Applicative.html#t:Parser) and a value of type `a` is it possible to generate the relevant command-line (in textual format)? (Basically, the exact reverse of what `optparse-applicative` is generally used for!)

For example, given something like...

```
data Args = {userName :: Text, userGroups :: Text }

parser :: Parser Args
parser = Args
  <$> (strOption $ long "name")
  <*> (many $ strOption $ long "group")
```

...how does one convert the following...

```
let args = Args { userName :: "testUser", userGroups :: ["system", "sudo"] }
```

...to...

```
--name=testUser --group=system --group=sudo
```

Comment: Can you give an example of a "relevant command-line"?

Comment: @Li-yaoXia I've added an example.

Comment: I see, that's an interesting idea, but probably not possible with optparse-applicative. You might get a couple of samples if you're lucky but you won't get to choose what goes in each field.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way in general. The relevant bits are:

```
data Parser a
  = forall x . MultP (Parser (x -> a)) (Parser x)
  | forall x . BindP (Parser x) (x -> Parser a)
  | -- ...
```

Since the `x`s of `MultP` and `BindP` are existentially quantified, the information about the suitable `x`s that could be used to produce your `a` is lost at runtime.

Comment: (I cribbed most of this answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51406985/791604).)